# How Text to Audio softwares works

Tags: text, audio

I want to create a software that can convert readable-texts(non-English) to Audio sound output.

After some searches what I have realized that most of the existing audio readers are too robotic and lacks the human-speech like effects.

I am looking for some algorithm/paper-work, which can give me some idea on how to proceed/implement such a thing.

or

Does anyone know, How some of the world's best Text-Reader software works?

My expectation are:

1. Reduced Robotic-like sound, and more of Human-like sound
2. High Quality Output
3. Light weight, yet Fast process speed

   **Please edit this question, if anyone thinks some points are missing on this aspect.

Comment: I am fairly sure a proper answer would be in the form of a very thick book on signal processing.

Comment: If anyone here knew how to do what you wanted, in a viable way, do you think they would be telling you how to do that, or do you think they'd be starting up a multi-billion dollar company?

Comment: @Lee I don't know such a thing could be so much demanding. I never thought it from money-making point of view; and I don't need to.

Comment: @Lee a lot of people have done far more complex and economically valuable software and released it as open source. I don't think the problem is about sharing secrets - the problem with the question is that the OP could as well ask how does the Large Hadron Collider work. The short answer will not satisfy him, and the detailed answer is rocket science that, since he had to ask, he will probably be unable to understand unless he spends some years studying it.

Comment: @Renan: They may have done that, but my point still stands... Whilst im sure there are more complex issues out there, the fact the problem the OP describes hasn't been solved sufficiently yet, means that your comparison against a solution to another problem that has been released openly, is pretty much void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some small steps might help you give some basic Idea of what happens-

1. You need to create a dictionary of words, each word with its name and sound.
2. Create your own signal processor, this will help you add effects to your sound, like you might want robotic, or a female version or something else.
3. Parse the text file you want to read in array formats, dividing each word and punctuations, to form an array and. eg. "I want to die, this isn't a correct way to live." this will form an array as {I:want:to:die:,:this:isn't:a:correct:way:to:live:.}
4. Use the punctuation to implement life like parameters like , for small pause and . for longer pauses in your audio reader.
5. Use the words to take out audio from your database(dictionary) list in point 1.
6. Play the whole array continuously with a pause between each array element, will work similar to spaces

I think these are major ways to do this. To make it faster you can use advanced sound processing tools, to cache small sound data and add data on fly while you are modulating sound signals.

Might this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be nice if you can tell us what kind of app you'll create (Movil, Web, Desktop) and also in what code you'll develop it (Php, Java, C++, etc). Because if you search in google, you'll find a lot plugins for website that convert text to audio that you can download them and see the code.

Also it's hard to find an app that not sound like a robot and if you find it maybe you'll pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

The "robotic" aspect of text to speech that you are concerned about is a matter of the quality of "prosody". This is an active research area. You could probably get a PhD for working on improving prosody in TTS systems. If you would like to read about current research you can try searching for "improving prosody in text to speech".

A big part of the problem is having an accurate model of speech prosody in a given language. The [thesis "MeLos: Analysis and Modelling of Speech Prosody and Speaking Style" by Nicolas Obin](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/72/36/70/PDF/MeLos_NO11_v2.pdf) (2012) contains a survey of the state of the art in speech prosody modelling. Or try searching for "text to speech prosody survey state of the art".